# Как преобразовать дату ,время в wpf mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

Хочу вывести данные с бд и у меня ругается на дату и время ,не знаю как преобразовать в wpf с datatime проблем нет а с data и time проблемы помогите ,кто может.

[image: Ошибка]

```
Connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    // создаем команду
                    MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection);
                  // получаем результат команды (массив строк)
                    MySqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

                    // перебираем стоки
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        // создаем экземпляр класса 
                        Zapisi Newzapisi = new Zapisi();
                        // и заполняем его поля
                        Newzapisi.Day = Reader.GetDateTime("Day");
                        Newzapisi.Time = Reader.GetDateTime("Time");
                        Newzapisi.Client = Reader.GetString("Client");
                        Newzapisi.Description = Reader.GetString("Description");
                        Newzapisi.Master = Reader.GetString("Master");
                        Newzapisi.Telephone = Reader.GetString("Telephone");
                        Newzapisi.Price = Reader.GetInt32("Price");
                        // добавляем экземпляр класса в список записей
                        ZapisList.Add(Newzapisi);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // обязательно закрываем соединение
                    // ресурсы сервера конечны
                    Connection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: хм, а причем тут вообще WPF? Ошибка появляется на строке 57, правильно? Это что за строка в приведенном коде?

Comment: Newzapisi.Day = Reader.GetDateTime("Day");
                        Newzapisi.Time = Reader.GetDateTime("Time");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySqlDataReader.GetDateTime Method (String)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetDateTime_1.htm)

> MySql allows date columns to contain the value '0000-00-00' and datetime columns to contain the value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Преобразование времени - не предусмотрено, т.е. `Newzapisi.Time = Reader.GetDateTime("Time");` - неправильно.

PS. А изначально неправильно - разделять дату и время на два поля.

Comment: а как правильно? Мне надо дату и время по одельности ,ведь в mysgl есть отдельно time и data

Comment: @Ученик Эти дата и время связаны и образуют единое значение даты-времени, или они не связаны?

Comment: Связаны но хотелось бы сделать раздельно дату и время так нельзя?

Comment: Лучше сделать одно поле и выделять нужный компонент соотв. функцией, когда это нужно. Но если очень хочется - читай поле времени как строковое, а потом преобразуй в Time.

Comment: ок спасибо вы помогли